# HTML5 Video muted but still playing

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

Title pretty much says it all. I have a video which automatically starts playing when arriving on the page.

In the HTML code I have put muted="muted". And here comes the weird part. When looking at the controls it clearly is muted, but the music is still playing and can be heard. Even when I looked at the HTML5 Video example on W3Schools it plays the music while muted.

Is there any way, trough jQuery for example to bypass this? I have a jQuery line in it which stick the muted to the video but that has no effect.

Here is the HTML code is use:

```
<video id="video" width="640px" height="350px" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" muted="muted">
            <source src="intouchables.f4v" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

Hope you can help me out. The jQuery line is as following:

$("video").prop('muted', true);

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure as to why the `muted` attribute is malfunctioning when defined within the `video` tag. However, this is what you can do :

Firstly, remove the `muted="muted"` attribute from the video tag. Keep it simply as :

```
<video id="video" width="640px" height="350px" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls">
    <source src="intouchables.f4v" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Now, define a function that on loading of the page, mutes the video.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('video');
    element.muted = "muted";
}
```

I have verified this, and it works.

Comment: you're my hero, I can verify that is working. I'll try reporting the bug. Great thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using `element.muted = true;` as this is actually a boolean property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: to solve the problem with "property doesn't exists", set the type: var element = document.getElementById('video') as HTMLVideoElement;

Answer (score 58):

In Angular case, one can try **[muted]="'muted'"**, It is working for me.

```
<video id="video" style="width:100%; height:100%" autoplay [muted]="'muted'" loop>
  <source src="./../../assets/video/model-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: You're right thank you. I replaced 'muted' by true as value, the muted attribute is named as a boolean property.

Comment: I don't know why this version suddenly fixed my issue, but I had the src on the video element.  Since I only had one source I didn't think it would make a difference but it now works.

Answer (score 36):

There is no real new information in this answer. Just trying to bring this question up to date and hopefully reduce the number of people wasting a whole day on it (like I just did).

---

As far as I can tell (especially since this question is so old) that `muted` has **never** worked when the video is dynamically added to the page. And since `muted` doesn't work then `muted autoplay` won't work either.

I think what happens is that the browser makes certain decisions on page load, and for some super odd reason, a video later to the page added will NOT mute even if it has `muted` property. This I believe is a bug in Chrome, not occurring for me in Safari - but it looks like we're stuck with it for now.

Google's [blog entry on autoplay/mute](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) is only a year old, and provides the following insight:

> Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

> - Muted autoplay is always allowed.
> - Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>
>   - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>   - On the desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with
>     sound.
>   - On mobile, the user has added the site to his or her home screen.
> - Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

There's just one major thing missing!

> - The 'muted' HTML attribute only takes effect when the video is present in the HTML at initial load. This also applies to 'autoplay muted' videos.

So what is the impact of this:

> - If a video with no sound is played programmatically it must be muted first. Therefore if a dynamic video is added to the page you must explicitly set `video.muted = true` after it is added to the DOM (or right before you play it).
> - If you try to execute `video.play()` programmatically (eg. when someone scrolls down past a muted video and you want it to play) then the video must be muted first.

I ran into this in Angular and spent way too much time assuming it was related to the fact I was using a template, or something Angular related.

I made a test app on StackBlitz. You will need to uncomment the line `// video.muted = true` to get it to work properly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ze4t9y

The other important things to realize are:

- Even if a video doesn't actually HAVE sound it must be muted. Test with the '[bunny](https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4)' video if you need to.
- The newer 'media engagement' rules outlined in the blog can confuse the heck out of you when testing a page because you will have interacted with the page. What you must do is close the browser, or open a new window in incognito mode - in order to reset this engagement rule (see blog entry).

The error you'll see in the browser if you try to play a non muted video when the user hasn't 'engaged' with the page first is shown below. If you aren't seeing this message for a non muted video then Chrome may have allowed the video to play because you interacted with the page.

[image]

And finally, if you are using Angular (where everything is dynamically added), the following works to mute the video:

```
 @ViewChild('bunnyVideo', { read: ElementRef }) bunnyVideo: ElementRef;
```

Then when you want to play it:

```
 const video: HTMLVideoElement = this.bunnyVideo.nativeElement;

 // explicitly mute it...
 video.muted = true;

 // ...before attempting to play
 video.play().catch((err) => {
    alert('video error ' + err);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! that was it for me :)

Comment: I have the same problem in Angular. You saved me a whole day. Thank you very much !

Comment: TLDR: Set video.muted = true immediately after adding it to the DOM

Comment: In some cases you could also just assign `src` dynamically instead of rendering the video element conditionally.

Answer (score 17):

This work fine for me.

```
<video oncanplay="this.muted=true" id="video" width="640px" height="350px" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls">
            <source src="intouchables.f4v" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 6):

looks like this muted stopped working in chrome 64. still works in 63.

Comment: I also confirm that the `muted` video tag is broken in chrome 64. workaround: It seems it still works if the video element is placed on a page that has been rendered on the page's initial load. You can also apply mute to the element directly using JavaScript. 
see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629652/chrome-64-update-muted-tag-no-longer-working-in-video/48651746#48651746

Comment: Not working for me in Chrome 65 either. My current workaround is `<video src="foo.mp4" autoplay oncanplay="this.muted=true"></video>`

Answer (score 4):

```
<video preload= "true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop = "loop" muted>
    <source src = "video/Real-Estate.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

To mute via HTML5 directly instead of jQuery, you can also use `volume="0"` within the video tag, i.e:

```
<video preload="true" autoplay="" volume="0" poster="img/example.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<video class="" autoplay loop [muted] = "'muted'">
    <source src= "video url/video path" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
```

// Try this. It is correctly working fine with my device. when your video has a sound browser(google) tries to block the video. So video does not autoplay. So try to mute the audio. By mentioning only muted it did not work with me. So I tried the binding method. Now it is working fine with me. I suggest trying this once

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your audio codec is set to AAC when producing a video. I had the same problem using OpenShot where the default setting is AC3.

Answer (score 0):

for html5 use:

```
<video controls loop muted height="" width=""  >

  <source src="" type="video/(put format here ex .mp4)" />
<source src="" type="video/(put another format of same video here if there is one ex .wav)" />
Your browser does not support the HTML5 element.
</video>
```

this is w3c good to go.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

try this for unmuted videos in html5

```
   var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
   video.removeAttribute("muted");
   video.muted = false;
   video.volume = 0.5;
```

and in tag html try this

```
<video muted autoplay id="myVideo">
</video>
```

resolve bugs if you use google chrome and you dont need use a controls attribute in your tag video for show a sound option

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to mute the video

**Option 1** - Add [muted]="'muted'"

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop controls [muted]="'muted'" *ngIf="data?.externalURL" > <source [src]="data?.externalURL" type="video/mp4" /> Your browser does not support the video tag </video>
```

**Option 2** - Add oncanplay="this.muted=true"

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop controls oncanplay="this.muted=true" *ngIf="data?.externalURL" > <source [src]="data?.externalURL" type="video/mp4" /> Your browser does not support the video tag </video>
```