# How to unmute html5 video with a muted prop

Tags: javascript, html, video

I've created a simple video block with muted (for mobile autostart) but now i can not change the mute state...

I used that [repository](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video) , fiddle link would be great.

So far i've tried this with no luck.

**HTML**

```
<video width="640" height="264" muted autoplay webkit-playsinline src="'+videoURL+'"></video>'
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click",".containerVolume",function(e){
        if(isMuted){
            $('video').prop('muted', false);
        }
        else{
            $('video').prop('muted',true);
        }
});

var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
      if (location.search === '?enabled=false') 
      {
      } else if (location.search === '?enabled=true') {
           enableVideos(false);
      } else {
         enableVideos();
      }
      function enableVideos(everywhere) {
          for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
             window.makeVideoPlayableInline(videos[i], !videos[i].hasAttribute('muted'), !everywhere);
          }
      }
```

Comment: this works: `document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].removeAttribute("muted");`

Answer (score 45):

Try this:

```
function toggleMute() {

  var video=document.getElementById("myVideo");

  video.muted = !video.muted;

}
```

Check example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b2oc1ca0/1/)

If your own code is not working, try adding an `id` to your video/element you want the click to register on and using:

```
var video=document.getElementById("myVideo") ;   

$(video).on("click", function(e){
  video.muted = !video.muted;
});
```

Comment: removed the muted attr but still the video is mute

Comment: I have updated my answer. `.muted` is the proper way, if this is not working on your particular code there may be other issues. Please check the linked JSFiddle for a working example.

Comment: According to the link for the repo you're using: _Limitations:

Needs user interaction to play videos with sound (standard iOS limitation)_ Not sure you can work around an OS limitation.

Comment: the video autoplays by itself but without sound and then it can not be unmute even by the user action

Comment: This would be much easier to help with if we had a link to either your _live code_ or a _fiddle with the problem reproduced_.

Comment: this is the [link](http://bfred-it.github.io/iphone-inline-video/demo/) of an autoplay video but can not make it unmute

Comment: Simple and complete.

Answer (score 4):

[Glen's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39042127/2410203) is spot on, I just want to provide insight for why it was not working for Özgür, the OP (and myself, which is what led me here).

Basically it comes down to the fact that the muted [property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_video_muted.asp) and the muted [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_muted.asp) are different. It doesn't seem super well documented (that I have found), but the behavior I experienced is that the muted attribute (accessed via [element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and related methods) impacts the initial state, but toggling it impacts nothing. On the other hand. It seems the muted property (accessed via videoEl.muted, as Glen pointed out), is how to change the muted state after page load.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `videoEl.muted`

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');

function toggleMute(){
  video.muted = !video.muted;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" width="300" controls muted src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>

<br><br>
<a onclick="toggleMute()">Toggle Mute</a>
```

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil - do you see the video?

Comment: yes , it start with mute and nothing changes, i will check later

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil – hmm, weird. It works for me. `.muted` is valid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/muted

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil – maybe a problem with Firefox? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32419889/484780

Comment: i will check later (your function is inline `toggleMute()` maybe that s why )

Answer (score 1):

You could simply mute/unmute with

```
document.getElementById("theIdOfYourVideoGoesHere").volume=0;
```

and

```
document.getElementById("theIdOfYourVideoGoesHere").volume=1;
```

(This thread appears to be two years old but today it was the number one top result in my google search)

---

Bilgisayar ne bilgiden anlar ne saygıdan. Çünkü o cansız bir düzenektir. O kadar.

Comment: does not work if video starts muted