# How to enable sound in video

Tags: html

I added a video from my local computer in my website by using video tag, everything is working fine but video is running without sound. Sound option is greyed-out. I tried using different Video but issue still persisted.

Audio file is working totally fine. Even video I used on HTML are working in Media players also. Idk what's problem here

Here is my code snippet

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> New Page</title>
  <style>
    video {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #666;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">

</head>
<header>
  <h1>Hyperlink</h1>
</header>
<main>

  This is test!!!!!!!!
  <div id='Absoulute'>




  </div>

  <video src="video/video.mp4" controls autoplay unmuted ></video>
  <br>
  <div>

    <h2> Audio</h2>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="video/audio.mp3">
    </audio>

  </div>

</main>
    
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of Webpage. Audio option is greyed out]

Comment: which browsers did you use to test it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unmute html5 video with a muted prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041960/how-to-unmute-html5-video-with-a-muted-prop)

Comment: Chrome 92 and Edge on Windows 11

Comment: @StephanBauerI tried using script. I even removed Autoplay, Muted still no sound nor it's looping

Answer (score 0):

You cannot autoplay unmuted as it is disabled in most of browsers
so use this

```
<video src="video/video.mp4" controls autoplay muted ></video>
```

Comment: I tried still neither video is unmuted nor its looping. Tried in many browsers

Answer (score 0):

Remove `unmuted` because it is an invalid video attribute. If you want to muted the video try [`muted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-muted).

```js
<video src="video/video.mp4" controls autoplay></video>
```

Demo [codepen](https://codepen.io/tran-nhat-anh/pen/zYwGOLJ)

Comment: Thanks for help it worked but still its not looping. Video is stopping after specified time

Comment: If you want to loop the video, add `loop` attribute as`<video src="video/video.mp4" controls autoplay loop></video>`.