# Chrome 64 Update - muted tag no longer working in <video>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/kaldenfi/rpmk93wm/3/

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <section ng-if="url">
     <video id="player1" playsinline autoplay loop muted volume="0.0">
       <source ng-src="{{url | trusturl}}" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
   </section>
</div>
```

After updated to chrome 64, this is no longer muting my video. If i take the video outside of the ng-if and hardcode the url it works as it should

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay found a temporary solution, if I move the ng-if to the `source` tag, it mutes it correctly.

Chrome 64 must be doing something when the page first loads it's looking for any video tags, so if your video tag isn't there on load it won't run the muted tag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in an Ember application I am working on.

The 2 solutions I had:

1. move the `<video>` tag(s) to the index.html, like you similarly did
2. create a function that can be called on an `init` or `window.onload` hook

   `mutePlayer1VideoHack() {
     const player1Video = document.getElementById('player1');
     player1Video.setAttribute('muted', true);
   }`

I prepended the function name in #2 with `Hack` in the case this is a true Chrome 64 bug that will be fixed. I am going with solution #1 for my case