# Use play() video method with audio muted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

I added a play button to an HTML background video on my site so users can choose to play video or not. Video was added with code below:

```
<video id="mobilevideo" class="video-full" loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="<?php echo esc_url( $videofile ); ?>" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I added the control buttons and styled them so the icons can change from play to pause as the user toggles the button. I did same for mute and unmute.

```
<a class="playcontrol" href="#">
    <img src="<?php echo $pause; ?>" width="18" height="" alt="overlay" class="play">
    <img src="<?php echo $play; ?>" width="18" height="" alt="overlay" class="pause">
</a>
<a class="soundcontrol" href="#">
    <img src="<?php echo $pause; ?>" width="18" height="" alt="overlay" class="unmute">
    <img src="<?php echo $play; ?>" width="18" height="" alt="overlay" class="mute">
</a>
```

I however do not want the audio to play by itself. I want users to be able to click another button to enable audio or not.

```
var mobileVideo = document.getElementById("mobilevideo"); 
$(".video-mobile video").prop('muted', true);

$(".video-mobile .playcontrol").click(function () { 
    if (mobileVideo.paused) {
        mobileVideo.muted = true;
        mobileVideo.play(); 
        $(this).addClass('playsound'); // changing icon for button
    } else {
        mobileVideo.pause(); 
        $(this).removeClass('playsound'); // changing icon for button
    }
});

$(".video-mobile .sound-control").click(function () {
    if ($(".video-mobile video").prop('muted')) {
        $(".video-mobile video").prop('muted', false);
        $(this).addClass('playsound'); // changing icon for button
    } else {
        $(".video-mobile video").prop('muted', true);
        $(this).removeClass('playsound'); // changing icon for button
    }
});
```

The problem I have is that although both buttons work well. The play button causes the video to be unmuted when clicked. I do not want that but I am not sure how to make the play button only control play and pause without the audio while the other button would control the audio.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Video muted but still playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111917/html5-video-muted-but-still-playing)

Comment: Not really. I think the key difference is that my code do not auto-play video. I had no problem muting videos that autoplay. The problem is with manually playing and pausing videos. Doing that seems to automatically unmute the video too.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually sorted this out by using Video Event. Removed the line - `mobileVideo.muted = true;` and added below to the script to mute the video once it starts playing:

```
mobileVideo.addEventListener('play', (event) => {
    mobileVideo.muted = true;
});
```

Still play a few milliseconds before the function kicks in but it works overall. It's barely noticeable. Suggestion to fine-tune this is welcome though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `volume` property and set it to `0`. It’s an interval between 0-1. In this case it would be: `mobileVideo.volume = 0;`.